# Increase the width of Content View programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, contentview

How to increase the width of content view, add some space margin between the elements and distribute equally. Below is the swift code what have i tried.

```
    class EatTypeCell : UICollectionViewCell{
        @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            self.contentView.applyViewStyle(isRound: true, borderColor: UIColor.ColorGray, borderWidth: 1.5, backGroundColor: UIColor.ColorWhite)
            self.lblTitle.applyStyle(labelFont: UIFont.applySemiBold(fontSize: 11.5), textColor: UIColor.ColorGray)     
        } 
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height = collectionView.frame.height/2 - 14
        var width : CGFloat = 0
        if self.colEat == collectionView {
        width = self.arrayMeal[indexPath.row].name.sizeOfString(font: UIFont.applySemiBold(fontSize: 11.5)).width + 50
        } 
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
```

[image: The Result image what i am getting here]

[image]

Comment: set + 50 to  8 or 16 than try

Comment: @mohammed-nabil: While applying styling to label you seem to use `UIFont.applySemiBold(fontSize: 11.5)` font of size 11.5 where as while calculating the size of string you use `UIFont.applySemiBold(fontSize: 10)` a font of size 10? Whats the logic in there?

Comment: @JatinRB I want to see same width size not like based on text length

Comment: @SandeepBhandari please check the updated code

Comment: @MohammedNabil than please share this(sizeOfString) code as well so i can help you.